# How to seal subtitle on the video permanently ? ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am able to add subtitle to my mp4; however, when i upload it on youtube, the subtitle is gone, disappeared.

So i am asking if there is any method to make the subtitle on the video (forever, permanently, seal it, burn it, force everyone watch the video with subtitle, can't even turn it off manually)

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -disposition:s:0 forced \
permanently-subtitle-video-please.mp4
```

i dont like the design of youtube subtitle, so i would love to upload my video + subtitle as one thing.

sorry i a not an English native speaker, hope you understand what i am trying to ask. thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but can't you upload the SRT file to the video for use by YouTube's subtitles?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara  
i just dont like the design of youtube subtitle, and i want the sub-title always on. any idea?

Comment: Try: https://superuser.com/

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara hi alex, you mean i can find an answer there? or should i post a new question over there?

Comment: Search first, if you can't find an answer, ask over there. It's off-topic here.

Comment: ok thanks! let see if i can find an answer there

Comment: Use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter. [Several](https://superuser.com/a/895197/110524) [examples](https://superuser.com/a/521741/110524) on Super User.